# 1回だけ呼び出される内部のメソッドはどう書くべきなのか

Tags: javascript

```js
function A(){};

A.prototype.a = function() {
  // 他のなんらかの処理

  // A.prototype._bの呼び出し
  this._b();
};

A.prototype._b = function() {};
```

`A.prototype._b` は `A.prototype.a` でのみ利用され、 Node や Browserify で `require('A')` として扱うモジュールを想定しています。( `module.exports` は省略します)

この場合 `A.prototype._b` はどう書くのが望ましいといえるでしょうか。

上記のコードは個人的には違和感があり、

- パブリックであること
- 1度しか呼び出さないのにも関わらずメソッドであること

などが挙げられます。それらを解決するとなれば、

**ex1: プライベートで、関数にした場合**

```
function A(){};
var _b = function();

A.prototype.a = function() {
  _b();
};
```

のようなコードや、

**ex2: ベタ書きで問題ないと判断した場合**

```
function A(){};
// var _b = function();

A.prototype.a = function() {
  // _b()と同様の処理をここにベタ書き
};
```

といったコードが思い浮かびます。

しかし、

- `var _b = func~`とするのは独立していて違和感がある
- であれば `A._b = func~` のような形はどうか
- いずれも納得できないのであれば、「1回だけ呼び出すならなんでもかんでもベタ書き」ということでいいのか

このようにどうすべきなのか判断がつきません。

これでは自分の中で考えても仕方がないので、結局のところこのケースでは `A.prototype._b` はどう書くのがベストなのか教えていただけないでしょうか。

JavaScript なのでそこまでプライベートにこだわっているわけではなく、一般的な実装として望ましい形を知りたいと思っています。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `.a`の中でしか使われない、そして他からは見られたくないということであれば、`.a`の中で書く(ベタにしても関数にしても)。ということでいいと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。関数の場合```.a```を呼び出す度に関数を生成することになると思うのですが(違うのでしたら勉強不足ですみません)、それは過剰に気にしすぎでしょうか。

Comment: _関数の場合.aを呼び出す度に関数を生成することになる_ javascriptでどのように実装されるのかは知りませんので実際の所は知りません(なので私の戯言を聞いても詮無いことです)が、インタプリタ的にその文章に出会う度に解釈しなおすという実装ではないんじゃないですかね。`var _b=func～` という部分はいわば関数リテラルなんだからリテラルとして登録しておいてスコープにはいれば使えるというようになってる（毎回解釈されるわけではない、`var n=1`のような感じをイメージしてます）んじゃないかなと思います。単なる関数ではなくクロージャーの場合には環境を付属させる必要があるでしょうから毎回「生成される」んでしょうけど、その場合でも普通のローカルスコープのオブジェクトとそれほど大差ないんじゃないでしょうか。もし生成されるとしても１回だけ生成されるというようにということならフラグ的なもので切り替えられるような気がします。(そんなに気にするぐらいなら埋め込んだ方がいいような気がします。)

Comment: 最近のJavaScirptエンジンの質を考えると素直に毎回パースして云々というわけでもなさそうですね。だったら普通にメソッドの中に関数を書く形で良いと思えるようになりました。気になったのは、個人的にそういう記述に納得がいかないといったことではなく、そういった書き方は自分以外の誰かからみて適当なコードといえるのかということで、いくつか意見をいただいてそう気にすることもないように感じました。ご丁寧にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

JavaScriptそんなに詳しくないですが書いてみました。スコープを制限してそれっぽく見せる作戦

```
var A = function() {}
(function(A){
    var b = function(obj) { console.log('name=' + obj.name); };
    A.prototype.a = function() { b(this); }
 })(A);

var b = new A();
b.name = 'fkm';
b.a(); // name=fkmをログに出力
```

Answer (score 2):

モジュールの書き方と絡めて、2 通り挙げたいと思います。

### 例 1

たぶん、一般的なのかなと思われる形式です。モジュール自体の基本形は、

```
(function () {
   this.moduleA = function () {};
}());
```

もしくは、

```
(function () {
   this.moduleB = {};
}());
```

もしくは、

```
var moduleC = (function () {
   return {};
}());
```

などとすればよいでしょう。

上記のうち、`moduleC` のパターンを取り、プライベートなメソッドを含めた初期化の記述サンプルを下に示します。（私は、変数名の後ろに `_` を付けることをプライベートな変数の命名ルール
としています。）

```
var moduleC = (function () {
  var module = {};

  // PRIVATE
  function b_() {
  };

  // PUBLIC
  module.a = function() {
    b_();
  };

  return module;
}());
```

一般的なモジュールの書き方は、[Eloquent JavaScript: Chapter 10 - Modules](http://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html) が参考になると思います。

### 例 2

以下は、「一般的ではない」と思います。以下の例では、プライベートメソッドは隠されてはいません。ただ、この書き方はパフォーマンスが良いし、ソースコード解析ができるので、私は個人的にこっちを好んでいます。

```
(function () {
  /**
   * @public
   * @constructor
   */
  A = function(){};

  /** @public */
  A.prototype.a = function() {
    // ...
    this.b_();
  };

  /** @private */
  A.prototype.b_ = function() {
    console.log( this)
  };
}());
```

ここから考えると、足りないのは、 [jsdoc](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-private.html) の記述だけかなと感じました。

Comment: 1の方法は初めて見ました。勉強になります。プライベートなメンバを実現したいというより、プライベートなメンバをどのように記述すれば誰もが読みやすいコードといえるのか、といったことが知りたくて質問しました(主観的な問題なので難しいことだとは思いますが)。質問の文章がまずかったようですし、そもそもそういった質問はここですべきではなかったのかもしれません。ありがとうございました。

Comment: そういうことですか。 JavaScript で private アクセスを実現することについては面白い話なので、構造の話かと思って飛びついてしまいました。そうであれば、ちょっと書き換えて、モジュールの書き方に絡めた回答に改めようと思います。お役にたてるかはわかりませんが、調べることもないと思いますし、10分ぐらいでできると思います。

Comment: 私も自分だけでコードを書くなら例2のような形を使うのですが、やっぱり一般的ではないようですね。わざわざ書き換えていただいてありがとうございました。参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

こちらの方が「bはメソッドaでしか使わない！」になりますね。。

```
var A = function() {}
A.prototype.a = (function() { 
    var b = function(obj) { console.log('name=' + obj.name); };
    return function() { b(this); }
})();

var c = new A();
c.name = 'fkm';
c.a(); // name=fkmをログに出力
```